# Is there any way to store xml string into cookie?

Tags: javascript, xml

Is that possible to store xml string into a cookie via javascript?

I tried this to store the xml,

```
var xml = response;
document.cookie = xml;
```

And I did this to read the cookey

```
var x = document.cookie;
alert(x);
```

I was expecting the whole xml document, but it only store the first tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Is there any way to store the whole xml document? Thanks a lot...

Comment: First, max. cookie size is 4093 bytes. Second, you need to URL or base46 encode such strings when storing in a cookie.

Comment: Use HTML5 localStorage instead of cookies

Comment: Done by using escape encode